# When does onDone event work for StreamSubscription in Dart?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, events, stream

```
void sample_stream_1() {
  final myGenerator = NumberCreator();
  final myStream = myGenerator.stream;
  myStream
        .listen(
            (data) => print('Data: $data'),
            onError: (err) => print('Error!'),
            cancelOnError: false,
            onDone: () {
                myGenerator.finish();
                print('Done!');
            },
        );
}

class NumberCreator {
  final _controller = StreamController<int>();
  var _count = 1;

  NumberCreator() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (t) {
      this._controller.sink.add(this._count);
      this._count++;
            if (_count > 10) t.cancel();
    });
  }

  Stream<int> get stream => this._controller.stream;
  void finish() => this._controller.close();
}

main(List<String> args) {
  sample_stream_1();
  print('waiting...');
}
```

The output is:

```
[Running] dart "./future_stream_demo.dart"
waiting...
Data: 1
Data: 2
Data: 3
Data: 4
Data: 5
Data: 6
Data: 7
Data: 8
Data: 9
Data: 10

[Done] exited with code=0 in 11.164 seconds
```

**onDone** event is not triggered, if I change `sample_stream_1()` procedure to this:

```
void sample_stream_1() {
  final myGenerator = NumberCreator();
  final myStream = myGenerator.stream;
  myStream
        .take(5)
        .listen(
            (data) => print('Data: $data'),
            onError: (err) => print('Error!'),
            cancelOnError: false,
            onDone: () {
                myGenerator.finish();
                print('Done!');
            },
        );
}
```

The output is:

```
[Running] dart "./future_stream_demo.dart"
waiting...
Data: 1
Data: 2
Data: 3
Data: 4
Data: 5
Done!
Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Cannot add event after closing
#0      _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:623:24)
#1      _StreamSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:900:13)
#2      new NumberCreator.<anonymous closure> (file:./future_stream_demo.dart:275:29)
#3      _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:397:19)
#4      _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:428:5)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)

[Done] exited with code=255 in 6.298 seconds
```

**onDone** event is triggered but it raises an exception also.

So:

1. Why does onDone event work for the prior one and not for the latter one?
2. Why do I get an exception in the latter one?
3. What's the correct way to implement onDone event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `onDone` callback is called when the `Stream` is closed. You're never closing the `Stream` in the first example you provided, so the callback is never called. If you call the closing function at the same time as the timer cancel, it works the way you expected.
   Example:

```dart
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (t) {
  this._controller.sink.add(this._count);
  this._count++;
        if (_count > 10) {
          t.cancel();
          finish();
        }
});
```

2. You get an exception with the second example because you're trying
   to add an event to  a `Stream` that you closed already. After the 5
   taken elements finishes, your `onDone`  method is called, closing
   the `Stream` from the `NumberCreator`, but the `Timer` is still ticking, and tries to add an event to the closed `Stream`. The confusion may have come from the fact that the `take` method returns a `Stream` that closes after it emits the provided number of events, in this case 5.
3. It's already being done correctly for the most part, you just never close the `Stream` so it's never expected to be called when you think it should.

Comment: First off, thanks for your answer, I have a question respect to this issue, but I cannot post it here, so check next post (answer) please, or do I need post it as a new question?

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα Your question isn't directly related to what you ask here. It's straying a bit too far from what was originally asked. I recommend you accept an answer here and delete your answer before it's deleted through review.

Comment: Done, I posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63786269/how-to-update-a-variable-maintaining-the-length-of-a-list-in-a-cascade-like-stru)