# How to update a variable maintaining the length of a list in a cascade-like structure?

Tags: list, dart

```
class CoinData {
  var _controller = StreamController<Map<String,dynamic>>();
  .....
  Stream<Map<String,dynamic>> getAllCurrentRates() {
    int numAssets = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    this.listAllAssets()
        .then((list) {
            if (list != null) {
                numAssets = list.length;
                List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(list)
                    .where((map) => map["type_is_crypto"] == 1)
                    .take(3)
                    .map((e) => e["asset_id"].toString())
                    .forEach((bitCoin) {
                        this.getCurrentRate(bitCoin)
                            .then((rate) => _controller.sink.add(Map<String,dynamic>.from(rate)))
                            .whenComplete(() {
                                if (++counter >= numAssets) _controller.close();
                            });
                    });
            }
        });

    return _controller.stream;
  }
  .....
}
```

The length of returned list is around 2500 and this value is assumed by `numAssets`, however as you see that list is modified later and therefore its length is less, then the evaluation (`++counter >= numAssets`) is incorrect. So, is it possible to fix that code maintaining its current structure?

`.take(3)` is temporal, it shall be removed later.

Comment: "however as you see that list is modified later and therefore its length is less".  I don't see any lists that are modified.  You do call a number of methods on an `Iterable` that return a *new* `Iterable`.  If you want `numAssets` to reflect the length of the `Iterable` resulting from `.where(...)`, you should just assign that result to a variable first.

Comment: Thank you for your scrupulous reply. I was thinking in a similar way, so I expanded the body of function but when running program it stays still without displaying any responses, so I tried another way.

Comment: Your approach does work, it would be like this:

```
    .map((e) => e["asset_id"].toString())
    ..every((_) => ++numAssets > 0)
    ..forEach((bitCoin) {
```

Comment: Prior code was another approach, this is with where:
```.where((map) {
 bool flag = map["type_is_crypto"] == 1;
 if (flag) ++numAssets;
 return flag;
}) 
```

Comment: However if I remove `.take(3)` the program becomes a mess. So I tried with another approach, but it is another question.