# Stream listen() method onDone callback not being called

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't get the onDone callback of a stream to be triggered.

I've tried cancelling the stream subscription and closing the stream controller but it doesn't work.

Here's a basic example:

Sample Code:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  final streamController = StreamController<int>();

  final streamSubscription = streamController.stream.listen(
    (event) => print('Value emitted: $event'),
    onDone: () => print('Task done'),
  );

  streamController.add(1);

  await Future<void>.delayed(Duration.zero);
  await streamSubscription.cancel();
  await streamController.close();
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Value emitted: 1
Task done
```

Actual Output:

```
Value emitted: 1
```

Comment: Have you seen this other post yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63784151/when-does-ondone-event-work-for-streamsubscription-in-dart

It might be able to help you investigate what's happening

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you call `streamController.close()` you call `streamSubscription.cancel()`, cancelling the subscription means that you will not recieve any more events on said subscription, including `onDone`, that's the reason why you don't get the final event. Removing `streamSubscription.cancel()` or moving it to after closing the stream will work.

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  final streamController = StreamController<int>();

  final streamSubscription = streamController.stream.listen(
    (event) => print('Value emitted: $event'),
    onDone: () => print('Task done'),
  );

  streamController.add(1);

  await Future<void>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  // await streamSubscription.cancel() // comment this out.
  await streamController.close();
  await streamSubscription.cancel(); // <- here it is fine
}
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe it's that simple. Thanks a lot!

Comment: this is not work on complicated cases